Error al cargar la imagen en S3 AWS desde C# .Net framework
Al intentar cargar una imagen del sitio web al depósito de AWS, aparece un error de ajax. Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto la aplicación desde Visual Studio, se carga sin problemas.  La región de mi cuenta es USEast2.
El código C# que uso en el controlador es el siguiente:
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accesskey, secretkey, bucketRegion);
    var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
    try
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
            var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                FilePath = filePath,
                StorageClass = S3StorageClass.StandardInfrequentAccess,
                Key = keyName,
                CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
            };
            fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
            fileTransferUtility.Dispose();
        }
        ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";
    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
    {
        if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null &&
            (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId")
            ||
            amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Check the provided AWS Credentials.";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Error occurred: " + amazonS3Exception.Message;
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

Probé otras opciones que encontré en línea sin resultados.El código es el siguiente:
IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(accesskey, secretkey, bucketRegion);  

FileInfo localFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\test.txt");  
string destPath = @"folder\sub-folder\test.txt"; // <-- high-level s3 path uses \
 
S3FileInfo s3File = new S3FileInfo(client, "my-bucket-name", destPath);  
if (!s3File.Exists)  
{  
    using (var s3Stream = s3File.Create()) // <-- create file in S3  
    {  
        localFile.OpenRead().CopyTo(s3Stream); // <-- copy the content to S3  
    }  
}

El error ocurre cuando el sistema busca la imagen en la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo. En el depurador tuve que copiar la imagen a la carpeta del proyecto.
Cabe mencionar que en el depurador la aplicación se ejecuta en la dirección https://localhost:44310/ mientras que en AWS se ejecuta en la dirección proporcionada por Amazon en el dominio elasticbeanstalk.com
Otra opción que he probado es con el siguiente código y se presenta el error en la línea
InputStream = localFile.OpenRead(),
Allí el error dice que no puede encontrar la ruta del archivo.
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
{
InputStream = localFile.OpenRead(),
BucketName = bucketName,
Key = path // <-- in S3 key represents a path
};

PutObjectResponse response = client.PutObject(request);

Hasta el momento él cambio más reciente que he hecho para subir la imagen es este código:
IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(PassBucket, SecretKey, bucketRegion);
FileInfo localFile = new FileInfo(archivoImagen.FileName);
string path = "Productos/" + nombreimagen;// es el PATH EN EL BUCKET DE AWS
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
{
InputStream = localFile.OpenRead(),
BucketName = bucketName,
Key = path // <-- in S3 key represents a path  
};

PutObjectResponse response = client.PutObject(request);

archivoimagen viene de la petición en el controller la cual está así:
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RegistrarProductoAWS(string objeto, HttpPostedFileBase archivoImagen)


No termine de entender tu error.. es que no encontras el archivo a subir???

correcto, cuando intento cargarlo a AWS S3 me dice que no encuentra la ruta. Según he leído la razón por la que la lectura falla es porque estoy intentando leer desde un área fuera de tu sitio web y sería una violación de seguridad permitirle hacer esto, pero debe haber una solución porque existen infinidad de aplicaciones que cargan imágenes.

Una solución sería guardar el archivo en una ubicación temporal del equipo cliente y desde allí copiarla a AWS, pero no he podido hacerlo.

si si.. yo lo hago de otra forma, pero lo hago... el problema es que tu archivo no esta en un lugar fisico todavia desde el cual tengas acceso para hacer el upload... yo uso un objeto cliente de tipo IAmazonS3... si usas el mismo tipo, podemos probar otra cosa...

no he usado el IAmazonS3, te agradezco me digas como puedo hacerlo.

Agrega porfa la libreria que estas usando en tu pregunta y como la estas inicializando...

Para este caso, las librerías que utilizo, etre otras son: using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;
using Amazon; ya hice pruebas con iamazon3 y en la actualización que hice de la pregunta, el ultimo código es el que estoy utilizando.

Parece que el inconveniente no es de AWS, abrí una cuenta en cloudinary para subir las imágenes y el resultado es el mismo. Cuando ejecuto desde visual studio, el cargue se hace perfecto, pero desde la aplicación desplegada en AWS no funciona, no carga la imagen. El inconveniente es la entrega del archivo de imagen desde el input al repositorio. Es mi primera aplicación web y el CRUD a la BD no tengo problemas, agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Es que tu problema es que no esta el archivo que dijiste que subiste.. separa tu problema en pedazos.. tu primer problema es que el archivo sea subido al lugar desde cual lo queres mandar a s3... lograste subir el archivo al servidor primero???

Amigo bianchi, el archivo sube al servidor solo cuando ejecuto la aplicación desde visual studio y veo la imagen en el bucket de aws, pero cuando hago el despliegue en aws, que es el servidor donde tengo la aplicación, ya no lo hace, se realizan todas las actualizaciones de la bd pero la imagen no queda en el bucket.

eso es porque el archivo que queres mandar, no esta llegando al servidor.. me estas confundiendo en dos puntos.. uno es tu S3, y otra cosa tu despliegue (en aws).. al parecer, no pasa lo primero (porque si llega a visual studio desde algun lado.. desde donde?)... eso es lo que tenes que arreglar.. S3 es otro problema posterior...

Amigo Bianchi, muchas gracias por estar pendiente y aconsejarme, por fin pude solucionarlo. El inconveniente estaba en la forma como "recogía" el archivo para enviarlo, en modo local no había problema porque tenía acceso a mi ubicación, pero ya en despliegue no, por la seguridad que comentabas.  La forma como lo logré fue el archivo enviarlo como inputStream y los estoy guardando en firebase. Este es el código que utilicé en el controlador.                   string ruta_guardar = await cnfirebase.SubirStorage(archivoImagen.InputStream, nombreImagen,);

Para quien pueda tener el mismo inconveniente, logré solucionarlo mediante el método InputStream, éste es el código que coloqué en el controlador:
string ruta_guardar = await cnfirebase.SubirStorage(archivoImagen.InputStream, nombreImagen);

